# htaccess redirect rule for multiple URL params

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I need to get a redirect using htaccess

**From**: [http://example.com/go/zaym?source=`PARAM1`&keyword=`PARAM2`](http://example.com/go/zaym?source=%60PARAM1%60&keyword=%60PARAM2%60) but if there are no URL params I need also to get redirect with empty params

**To**: another domain [http://example2.com/sub_id=PARAM`&sub_id2=PARAM2](http://example2.com/sub_id=PARAM%60&sub_id2=PARAM2)

So I need to move value `source` to sub_id and value `keyword` to sub_id2

I'm trying so, but it's not working:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^source=([^&]+)&keyword=([^&]+)$
RewriteRule ^go/zaym http://example2.com/sub_id=%1&sub_id2=%2 [R,L]
```

Comment: When your previous question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65224714/) got closed, that does not mean please post the same thing again without any significant changes. This site is not a code-writing service, you are always expected to make an attempt yourself first. So show us that, and give us a proper problem description along with it.

Comment: If anything is unclear _to you_ about this site not being a code-writing service, then please go read [ask].

Comment: man...read other questions about redirect using htacces. I can not add anything more because anyway it's 500 error

Comment: _“I can not add anything more”_ - you can add what you tried, first of all. _“because anyway it's 500 error”_ - then go check what the error log has to say.

Comment: added how I tried

Comment: According to https://htaccess.madewithlove.be?share=0db5acd9-b2cc-4c9d-9fb5-ede582f43b2e, this should redirect you to `http://example2.com/sub_id=%60PARAM1%60PARAM26sub_id2=PARAM2?source=%60PARAM1%60&keyword=PARAM2` - do you really want to redirect to a _path_ `sub_id=PARAM&sub_id2=PARAM2`, or was that actually supposed to be a query string?

Comment: link is not working for me. I need to pass only sub_id  and sub_id2, without source and keyword.

Comment: _“without source and keyword”_ - those are passed, because the original query string is taken over, if you do not specify a new one. That’s why I asked you, whether you really wanted `sub_id=%60PARAM1%60PARAM26sub_id2=PARAM2` to be part of the _path_ of the new URL. According to your comment under Ravinder’s answer, you _don’t_ … but instead of answering that simple question, you just ignore it. And your problem description doesn’t reflect what you actually wanted in the first place.

Comment: ok, but now you understand. Do you have decision?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***EDIT(More generic way):*** With more generic way as per OP's comment one could try following, where no hard coding of `keyword` or `source` strings, then try following.

**With only query string condition check:**

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^[\w-]+=(.*)(?!=&)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example2.com%{REQUEST_URI}?sub_id=%1 [NE,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^[\w-]+=([^&]*)&[\w-]+=(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example2.com%{REQUEST_URI}?sub_id=%1&sub_id2=%2 [NE,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/go/zaym/?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://example2.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

**With URI + query string condition:**

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^[\w-]+=(.*)(?!=&)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/go/zaym/?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example2.com%{REQUEST_URI}?sub_id=%1 [NE,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/go/zaym/?$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^[\w-]+=([^&]*)&[\w-]+=(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example2.com%{REQUEST_URI}?sub_id=%1&sub_id2=%2 [NE,L]
 
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/go/zaym/?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://example2.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

Comment: it's good idea, but what if I don't know some params? it might be anything like
mydomain.com/go/zaym?keyword=2&SOMETHINGIDONTKNOW=1111, but I need to get redirect to example2.com?sub_id=2 WITHOUT params which I don'know. Or just mydomain.com?something=dontknow to example2.com

Comment: @АртёмДанилов, please do check my more generic answer once and let me know, I hope this time we should be GOOD :)

Comment: I use your second code: "With URI + query string condition:" and when I type mydomain.ru/go/zaym/keyword=3&a=1 I get https://example2.com/?sub_id=

Comment: @АртёмДанилов, ok I added `(?!=&)` in condition, could you please check now once and let me know then.

Comment: ok, that's working perfect. thank you very much for you time

Comment: @АртёмДанилов, oh man, THANK GOD my suggestion worked now :) cheers and happy learning on this great site.